# Visual Studio 2022 - CPU usage over 100% in built-in profiler

Tags: c#, visual-studio, profiling, .net-6.0, profiler

I've been profiling my `.NET 6` app which runs a couple of different algorithms.
When analysing the `Total CPU %` with the built-in profiler I was getting values over 100%, they were like `509.22%`or even `999.7%`.

I am not sure how to interprete such outputs, I've been looking through MS docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/cpu-usage?view=vs-2022) but still have trouble understanding values shown in the profiler.

I'd be glad if anyoine could explain this more or point me to some source where I could learn some more.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in visual studio. Unless maybe visual studio is overclocking your cpu for you (jk)

Comment: I've been thinking of some kind of bug, but maybe could this be connected to multi core CPU calculations? When it comes to multithreading, I have not enabled this by any means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it was a bug indeed.
After filing a bug report, Microsoft accepted this and the change is now pending release.

MS developer community topic: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022---CPU-usage-over-100/10066547?entry=problem